# OracleDrive returned null for h2 in functional tests

Tags: grails, integration-testing, datasource

Trying to add integration tests to an existing Grails 3.2.3 project, I've added the following lines to my application.yml:

```
environments:
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            pooled: true
            driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
            username: sa
            password:
```

However, when running my integration tests, I get a message saying that the OracleDriver returns null:

> ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@2da84919 returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

I'm in the test environment, having added the '-Dgrails.env=test' flag in my JUnit VMOptions in Intellij IDEA. I tried commenting the default datasource, with no success.

PS: I also get the error when commenting all datasources from application.yml, event the test one.
PPS: when running the integration tests through Gradle, the problem disappears.

Comment: Is the `test:` key underneath an `environments:` key?

Comment: Yes it is, I'll edit the snippet to make it clear.